# How to Set Background Color of Editor in MPLab X?

Tags: c, mplabx

New to MPLab X, and just trying to navigate between bugs and getting used to it.  I've already found that 'C' formatting is apparently not part of 'All Languages'.

In Mac, I've found:
mplab_ide >> Preferences >> Fonts & Colors icon >> Syntax tab.

But there doesn't seem to be a way to set the background color of my editing environment.  The white is just a little intense on this monitor and I'd like to take it a bit darker if I'm going to be looking at this code a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: EE question uncertainty.

Comment: Did you try changing the background color under 'default' for all languages? That seemed to work for me with C code so I wasn't sure what you meant by C didn't seem to be part of all languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the MPLAB X IDE the language specific options only apply to specific elements that are identified as forming part of the language. It's useful to apply different colors for things such as comments however if applied to a character for example the background only changes for elements not identified as being something else:

[image: MPLAB X language specific colors]

Instead to make global changes to the background it's best to use the "all languages" selection. The language specific settings tend to inherit their background colour from those default settings so by making a single change it will change the background color of all elements:

[image: MPLAB X all languages colors]